# Android && Firebase realtime database data retrieving and writing

Tags: java, android, json, firebase-realtime-database

I have two things: `USERS` and `VALUES`. One user can have many values. I would like to configure my Firebase realtime database as follows:

```
 "Users" : {
    "-LP4S9ewWAuEOlXKEkRB" : {
     "id" : "-LP4S9ewWAuEOlXKEkRB",
     "token" : "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"
     }
    }
 "values":{
      userID: same as "id" in the users element,
      userToken: same as "token" in the users element,
      value: 13
    }
```

I have succeded doing the first part (saving the users) but for the values, the values of each new user of my application overwrites the ones of the others.
this is my code:

```
final String userToken =  sharedPreferences.getString("USER_TOKEN", "N/A");
//assign a personal id to the value
String valueId = dbRef.child("Values").push().getKey();
ValueData myValue= new ValueData(valueId, dataToSend);
dbRef.child("Values").child("UserToken").setValue(userToken);
```

Please help me!!
Thank you in advance.

Comment: in .child("Values")  the Values has capital V, while the JSON has small v. try changing .child("Values") to .child("values") at both the places

Comment: Thank you for your answer @Kishita but actually it is a mistake of mine. On firebase it's "Values" not "values"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that the children in your database are named `values` and `userToken` and **not** `Values` and `UserToken` as i see is in your code now, to solve this, please change the following line of code:

```
dbRef.child("Values").child("UserToken").setValue(userToken);
```

to

```
Map<String, Object> map = new HashMap<>();
map.put("userToken", userToken);
dbRef.child("values").updateChildren(map);
```

Comment: Hi @Alex mamo Thank you so much for your answer. It did not really tackle the thing but Hashmaps were a bright idea. I finally made it work after modifying your code. Thank you so much